# MDX Convert plain text URL to an anchor tag using Rehype/Remark plugins

Tags: mdxjs

I'm creating a blog using `Next.js` + `MDX-Bundler` and using rehype plugins to add additonal content to my `.html` file from `.mdx`. But I noticed that if I have a plain-text url, it doesn't get converted to an anchor tag. I also found a [reference](https://spectrum.chat/unified/general/how-do-i-prevent-rehype-from-turning-a-plain-text-url-into-an-anchor-element) mentioning that rehype doesn't do that.

But is there a way to do it?

This is possible in most of the popular website which take markdown input. Even this question in stack-overflow is based on markdown. If I enter a URL like this(*https://google.com/ or http://www.google.com/*), it gets converted to a URL in the preview. How to get similar functionality when converting mdx file into blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find resources that are specific to this particular issue. But I added [`remark-gfm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-gfm) to enable the use of tables in my markdown. And that solved this issue.

Below code is how you can [add remark-gfm into mdx-bundler](https://github.com/AnweshGangula/Nextjs-Blog/commit/9ee99fd01ca33bf412673e102d9a87759b61b9d6). And it is different based on the mdx loader you are using (like nextMDX, Next-mdx-remote, Next-mdx-enhanced etc...):

install remark-gfm with npm:

```
npm install remark-gfm
```

```js
// utils/mdx.js
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'

const POSTS_PATH = path.join(rootDir, "data/posts");

export const getSinglePost = async (slug) => {
    const filepath = path.join(POSTS_PATH, `${slug}.mdx`)

    const { code, frontmatter } = await bundleMDX({
        // source: sourceMDX,
        file: filepath,
        cwd: POSTS_PATH,
        xdmOptions(options) {
            options.remarkPlugins = [
                ...(options.remarkPlugins ?? []),
                remarkGfm,
            ];

            return options;
        },
    });

    return {
        frontmatter,
        code,
    };
};
```

Comment: where did you configure remark-gfm?

Comment: found an answer here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36310

Comment: @ColinD, thank you for sharing the link. Just to clarify - the links mentions how to add `remark-gfm` for `@next/mdx`. I've added the code you would need for `mdx-bundler`